# Issue in closing iframe using jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have following scenario.

On a product display page, when user clicks on sign-in, the sign-in popup opens up in an iframe.

```
jQuery.fancybox({
    'padding' : 0,
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none',
    'scrolling' : 'no',
    'autoDimensions' : false,
    'autoScale' : false,
    'width' : frameWidth,
    'height' : frameHeight,
    'type' : 'iframe',
    'href' : _this.attr("href"),
    'onComplete' : function() {
        $.fancybox.resize();
    },
    'onClosed' : function() {
        if(isReloadOnClose)
            closeAndRefresh();
    }
});
```

When user successfully signs-in, I am opening another popup which asks for user actions.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    window.jQuery('#fancybox-frame').remove();
    var productId = document.getElementById("productId").value;
    var skuId = document.getElementById("skuId").value;

    jQuery.fancybox({
        href: "/shop/wishlist-modal-add.jsp?productId="+productId+"&skuId="+skuId,
        type: 'ajax',
        centerOnScroll: true,
        onComplete: function(){
            jQuery.fancybox.resize();
        },
        onClosed: function(){
            $('#fancybox-content').css({width:'+=30px;'});
            jQuery.fancybox.resize();
        }
    });
});
```

The issue I'm facing is that the second popup is opening inside the first ifarme only, even though I'm removing the iframe.

Kindly help in resolving this.

Comment: try calling `parent.$.fancybox.close();` instead of `window.jQuery('#fancybox-frame').remove();`

Comment: Hey Pete, the statement provided above do actually closed the iframe, however it is not loading the next fancybox. Moreover none of the statements after parent.$.fancybox.close(); is getting executed. Also I wonder, would this work in cross domain network due to Same Origin Policy?

Comment: ah I guess because you are executing the script in the actual iframe, you can't close it.  try removing the previous line then call your new fancybox like this:  `parent.jQuery.fancybox({`  not sure about the same origin thing though

Comment: I was previously using the same function parent.jQuery.fancybox({ however it gave issue due to same origin policy on stage and I had to revert my changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close();
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I got error as parent.jQuery.fn.fancybox.close(); is not a function. Pardon me I'm ATG developer and not expert in jQuery.
Also as said earlier, wont this throw issue on cross domain platform?